# SQL script for DB creation from T-SQL or command line

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I searched SO for the solution but all answers means using interactive mode (SSMS) or third-party tools.

I need to obtain database creation script (with tables, SPs, triggers etc.) **not** from SSMS in interactive mode but from T-SQL or command line. There was *SqlPubWiz* utility in MSSQL older versions, but I cannot find it in 2014 (I use Express Edition).

So what should I do? Thank you.

Comment: Powershell could be an option.  Here's an example. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/powershell-script-all-objects-on-all-databases-to-files/

Comment: @StuartAinsworth, thank you for the link. I afraid using Powershell will be more complicated due security reasons but I'll take a look at this side too.

Comment: are you asking how to generate the create script or how to connect a command line tool to sql server?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I'm looking for a way to generate the create script. If there is certain utility like previous SqlPubWiz, which can be started from command line and generate script, this will solve my issue.

Comment: Otherwise, if such script can be generated via T_SQL, this will make me happy too.

Comment: You should probably read this [SQL Server 2012: Generate Scripts from command line](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56616/sql-server-2012-generate-scripts-from-command-line) over on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, thank you. It seems I should using PowerShell scripts (and I found some working for me). However, SMSS obviously does script generation without PowerShell, and I'm wondering in this way cannot be reproduced "by hands".